# Set the class of an html table within an R function

Tags: html, r, r-markdown, quarto

I'd like to add a specific additional class to a table output to `html` by a custom R function within a Quarto document. Ideally for any `df-print` setting. Preferably the class would be set within the function, but failing that by the chunk option.

Something along the lines of `class2` *or* `class1` per the below failed attempt:

````
---
title: "reprex"
format: 
  html:
    df-print: kable
---

```{r}
#| class-output: class1

simple_function <- \() {
  knitr::kable(
    tibble::tribble(
      ~a, ~b,
      1, 2,
      3, 4
    ),
    table.attr = "class='class2'"
  )
}

simple_function()
```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set `format='html'` so that `table.attr = "class='class2'"` works.

````
---
title: "reprex"
format: 
  html:
    df-print: kable
---

```{r}
simple_function <- \() {
  knitr::kable(
    tibble::tribble(
      ~a, ~b,
      1, 2,
      3, 4
    ),
    format = 'html',
    table.attr = "class='class2'"
  )
}

simple_function()
```
````

Comment: Thanks @shafee. By adding ` |> kableExtra::kable_styling("striped")` I can get the format back too.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use the `classes` option. This adds classes to the `<div>` element arround the table.

````
---
title: "reprex"
format: 
  html:
    df-print: kable
---

```{r}
#| classes: class1

simple_function <- \() {
  knitr::kable(
    tibble::tribble(~a, ~b, 1, 2, 3, 4)
  )
}

simple_function()
```
````